# ORACLE: CASE in WHERE clause taking more time for result

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

Employee Table has 100k data.

```
Select emp.* 
from Employee emp 
  inner join Department dept 
     on dept.Dept_no = (case when emp.Dept_NO= 11 then (select Id from CONSTANT where costant_name = 'ABC' )
                             else emp.Dept_NO end );
```

This query is taking too much time to run. How to make this query will run fast?

Comment: This was typo mistake. Ignore this. Now i corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid `select` within `case`, `cross join` with `constant` might help. Though, I guess it (the `constant` table) is small and returns only one row for this condition so that's fast enough anyway.

```
SELECT e.*
  FROM employee e
       CROSS JOIN constant c
       JOIN department d
          ON d.dept_no =
                CASE WHEN e.dept_no = 11 THEN c.id ELSE e.dept_no END
 WHERE c.constant_name = 'ABC';
```

Meanwhile, check whether columns involved into joining operation (`dept_no`) are indexed.

Explain plan might reveal some useful info.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should avoid `select` statement in the join clause.

You can use `left join` as following:

```
Select emp.* 
  from Employee emp 
Left join CONSTANT const on ( costant_name = 'ABC' ) 
inner join Department dept on dept.Dept_no = case when emp.Dept_NO <> 11 
           then emp.Dept_NO
           Else const.Id
           end ;
```

I have used `left join` with `constant` table in case there is no record in it which satisfies `costant_name = 'ABC'` then also query should return other records which matches the `employee` table.

Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks for reply but using this (LEFT JOIN ), still it is time taking to run.